# Об этимологии слова «шестнадцать»

Tags: этимология

Известно ли происхождение слова "шестнадцать"?

Comment: Вы уверены, что интересуетесь именно этимологией, а не морфологией, например? Этимология изучает происхождение слова, а тут с ним все очевидно. Шестнадцать < шесть + на(д) + дцать. ("Дцать" - это стяженное "десять"). Всё остальное уже за пределами этимологии.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Шестнадцать - сложное числительное, но из каких морфем оно состоит, учёные до конца не согласовали.

Есть такой подход: корни (два) - *шест* и *дцать*, приставка *на*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть и другой: числительное состоит из корня *шест* и суффикса *-надцать.*

> ...Числительные, оканчивающиеся на *-надцать* (пят-надцать), в которых
>   элемент *-надцать* является не вторым корнем, а суффиксом.

**[источник](http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part4.htm#i4)**

А этимология нужна ли?

Тогда не всё слово *шестнадцать*, а его составные:

**[ШЕСТЬ](http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-16289.htm)**

> Общеслав. Суф. производное (суф. -tь) от той же основы, что и латышск.
>   seši «шесть», нем. sechs «шесть», лат. sex «шесть» и т. д.

У него же - происхождение слова

**[ДЕСЯТЬ](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:9fjNbVKFZXkJ:https://shansky.lexicography.online/%25D0%25B4/%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D1%258F%25D1%2582%25D1%258C%20&cd=5&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)**

> Общеслав. Производное от desętъ «десятый», суф. образования от той же
>   основы, что и лат. decem и т. п. См. декабрь.

Смотрим, как словарь Шанского объясняет этимологию слова одиннадцать (этот принцип, или подход) справедлив для всех числительных оканчивающихся на *-надцать*:

**[ОДИННАДЦАТЬ.](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Z8pppxChoZoJ:https://shansky.lexicography.online/%25D0%25BE/%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B4%25D0%25B8%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B0%25D0%25B4%25D1%2586%25D0%25B0%25D1%2582%25D1%258C%20&cd=5&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)**

> Искон. Сращение др.-рус. эпохи *один на десяте* «один сверх десяти».